# JUnit Platform Launcher start TestClass with Injected Spring Beans

Tags: spring, junit, junit5

I try to run a testclass with the JUnit Platform Launcher. The Testclass contains some `@Autowired` Components. The issue is, that the injection doesn't seem to work. Is that even possible with JUnit Platform?
My code is as follows:

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mytests")
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

Component

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SomeBean {

  public String returnSuccess() {
    return "SUCCESS";
  }

}
```

Testclass

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeTests {

  @Autowired
  private SomeBean aBean;

  @Test
  public void testSuccess() throws Exception {
    String result = aBean.returnSuccess();
    assertTrue(result.equals("SUCCESS"));
  }

}
```

Controller which calls the test class

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

  @RequestMapping("/tests")
  public void executeTests() throws Throwable {

    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
        .selectors(selectPackage("com.mytests"), selectClass(SomeTests.class))
        .build();

    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();

    SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    launcher.execute(request);
    listener.getSummary();
  }

}
```

Comment: Why would you write a controller that calls the test class?

Comment: So that's just a test. I could also call it from another component or directly from the Application class. Do you mean the controller is the issue?

Comment: Before we can help you, we need to know the following: _What is it that you are trying to achieve_? What is it that you want to test?

Comment: So what I'm trying to achieve is to trigger a Testclass from a controller. Due to the pipeline structure this is a requirement. What I want to test is, that some entity is persisted after a specific service has received an event. The persistence is handled by a component which I have to inject into the Testclass. That's why I try to build a simple sample application which reflects this behaviour.

Comment: Well, at the very least, you'll need to replace `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Has anyone solved this problem?